# Query optimization for big data database

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have three collections with channel data, viewer data, and a viewing time of a viewer per channel per day.

A sample data record looks like this:

```
{
  channel: ObjectId("1"),
  viewer: ObjectId("1"),
  minutesWatched: 10,
  date: 2019-09-10
}
```

I try to get the top 10 viewers by minutes of a channel, the date field is included because I want to do it for certain timespans too.

My Query looks as follows:

```
db.channelviews.aggregate([
  { $match : { channel: ObjectId("5d790f220d3901329e4e7493")  } },
  { $group: { _id: { viewer: "$viewer"}, minutesWatched: { $sum: "$minutesWatched" } } },
])
```

My indexes are the following:

```
[
        {
                "v" : 2,
                "key" : {
                        "_id" : 1
                },
                "name" : "_id_",
                "ns" : "tvviewers.channelviewers"
        },
        {
                "v" : 2,
                "unique" : true,
                "key" : {
                        "channel" : 1,
                        "viewer" : 1,
                        "date" : 1
                },
                "name" : "channel_1_viewer_1_date_1",
                "ns" : "tvviewers.channelviewers"
        },
        {
                "v" : 2,
                "key" : {
                        "channel" : 1
                },
                "name" : "channel_1",
                "ns" : "tvviewers.channelviewers"
        },
        {
                "v" : 2,
                "key" : {
                        "viewer" : 1
                },
                "name" : "viewer_1",
                "ns" : "tvviewers.channelviewers"
        }
]
```

The problem I have is that this query is fast for a small amount of datasets. But takes about 90 seconds for 7 million datasets. Is there any solution to that?

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would do is `$sort` and `$limit` because you don't need more than 10 results

```js
db.channelviews.aggregate([{
    $match: {
      channel: ObjectId("5d790f220d3901329e4e7493")
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        viewer: "$viewer"
      },
      minutesWatched: {
        $sum: "$minutesWatched"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: { minutesWatched: -1 }
  },
  {
    $limit: 10
  },
])
```

Comment: Let me know how much performance does it improve and do you still need more optimization?